Latex text reversing with Babel package
I am using the babel package, which causes text-reversal when combined with amsmath.
The exact list of packages I use is:
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage[hebrew,english]{babel} % Workaround for babel and amsthm
\makeatletter
\let\everypar\o@everypar
\makeatother % End of workaround for babel and amsthm
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb,amsthm} 

I have tried adding texts in both English and Hebrew, and yet the Hebrew text appears to appear in a reverse-order of the characters within every string.
After failing to find a direct solution to this, I was looking for a command to reverse the text - That is, the order of the characters - within a string.
e.g., the text: "abc" should be "cba". The text "I - am here" should be "ereh ma - I". This should work for languages other than English as well.
I came across \reverse_string:n, which works for English, but not for other languages (It causes gibberish letters by corrupting their unicode).
Using this reverser:
https://www.alanshawn.com/leetcode/2020/06/05/leetcode-344-latex.html, where reversestring is defined:
\ExplSyntaxOn

\cs_set:Npn \reverse_string:n #1 {
    % convert token list to string
    \str_set:Nn \l_tmpa_str {#1}
    % use a sequence to save the string
    \seq_gclear:N \g_tmpa_seq
    % store each character in \l_tmpa_str in \l_tmpa_seq
    % use \exp_args:NV to expand the first argument
    \exp_args:NV \str_map_variable:nNn { \l_tmpa_str } { \l_tmpb_str }
        { \seq_gput_right:NV \g_tmpa_seq \l_tmpb_str }
    % pop each element in \l_tmpa_str from right side
    \bool_do_while:nn {
        % reverse the value of \seq_if_empty_p:N
        \bool_if:nTF {\seq_if_empty_p:N \g_tmpa_seq} {\c_false_bool} {\c_true_bool}
    }
        {   
            \seq_gpop_right:NN \g_tmpa_seq \l_tmpa_tl
            % generate output
            \tl_use:N \l_tmpa_tl
        }
}

\newcommand{\reversestring}[1]{\reverse_string:n {#1}}

\ExplSyntaxOff

I am trying to reverse a simple string (with and without a reversal, to see the difference):
\selectlanguage{hebrew}
\reversestring{אני בודק}
אני בודק

What I get is:

As you can tell, without using the reverse, the text appears by the opposite direction. With a reversal function, it appears to damage the characters' encoding and present totally different characters.
Update
The problem is due to the workaround of amsmath and babel:
\makeatletter
\let\everypar\o@everypar
\makeatother % End of workaround for babel and amsthm

Perhaps by altering \everypar, also the right-to-left settings are damaged.
Example for the Update:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english,hebrew]{babel}
\makeatletter
\let\everypar\o@everypar
\makeatother % End of workaround for babel and amsthm
 
\usepackage[top=2cm,bottom=2cm,left=2.5cm,right=2cm]{geometry}
\selectlanguage{hebrew}
\title{כותרת של מסמך}
\author{המחבר}
\date{כ"א בכסלו - \L{March 05, 13}}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\section{זוהי הכותרת בעברית}
זוהי הפסקה בעברית
גם אם אני ארשום את כל הדבר בעברית, זה יראה נהדר
\subsection{תת פסקה}
\subsubsection{תת של תת פסקה}
\selectlanguage{hebrew}
עברית ואז english ואז עברית
מלל בעברית, \L{Some English within the Hebrew} ועוד עברית לאחר מכן.

\begin{equation}\label{eq:visc}
\tau = \mu \frac{\partial u}{\partial y}
\end{equation}

\selectlanguage{english}
\section{English}

From here and on, the text is in English

\begin{equation}\label{eq:visc}
\tau = \mu \frac{\partial u}{\partial y}
\end{equation}




\end{document}

The document is Left-to-Right and presents the Hebrew text in reverse order.
Found solution:
Use \R{} and \L{} for texts, RTL and LTR, accordingly.

Please, post a minimal document showing the problem.

@JavierBezos Updated

That is not a minimal example others can copy and test as is.

@daleif The definition of reversestring is simply copied from alanshawn.

@TheEmeritus The problem is that anybody willing to help you, would have to first puzzle together all the code fragments and then guess all the missing bits to be actually able to compile your code.

Also note that we tend to not want to visit external URLs (which might rot over time) in order to get stuff relevant to your question (an exception are journal classes and similar)

Why such a complicated setup when expl3 has \tl_reverse:n? We could I guess provide \text_reverse:n if that's what's needed ...

@JosephWright It works perfect on English, not on other languages, as it messes up the encoding of the characters (both the example code I used and \tl_reverse:n from expl3).

Other than a grapheme-based reversal, that will always be the case: as I said, that would be \text_reverse:n (quite doable ...)

@JosephWright Some known reverse functions do not alter the order of characters for non-English languages, while others make it into gibberish by corrupting the characters' encoding. My idea is that it is somehow related to \selectlanguage{} from babel. Specifically, \text_reverse did not alter the order of the characters, while \tl_reverse corruped their encoding. Hence, I am looking for other text-reversal functions that will work (and not corrupt) for non-English text.

while as Joseph said it is possible to write a \text_reverse function, it is imho quite unclear what you are trying to achieve and if this is really the right tool for your problem. Side remark: you should not use utf8x anymore. utf8 is now the default, so you can remove the inputenc line completly.

@UlrikeFischer My recent update clarifies this. My initial problem was the combination of babel and amsmath. They simply don't work together. I came across the workaround I added above. This allows for them to work, yet made the Hebrew text appear LTR and in reverse order. After failing to find the cause, I attempted simply to reverse the Hebrew text (Yes, another workaround). However, I now believe I found the source of the issue, yet I'm still unaware of how to fix it (Instead of \everypar, just to find the relevent ones, perhaps? Or not to include the RTL parameter).

well I would say you should stop to pill up work arounds but tackle the source problem. And the first question here is why you don't use lualatex instead of pdflatex which can handle hebrew much better?

@UlrikeFischer Because I had hard time using it on overleaf. I think my question can be focused back to finding which parameter I should avoid of changing, and that should suffice.

@UlrikeFischer Seems like you missed the \R{} and \L{} options. Thanks for the advice anyways.
